# Checking if language is set in url with regex

Tags: php, regex

I am working on a multi language file. My urls look something like this:

```
http://www.example.com/en/about/info
http://www.example.com/nl/about/info
```

Now I use a small regex script that redirect the user when they use a link without language. The script looks like this:

```
preg_match('~^/[a-z]{2}/~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
```

This finds out whether there is a language set en|nl|de etc. This works fine on all links except for these:

```
http://www.example.com/en
http://www.example.com/nl
```

There is no trailing slash so the regex can not find the given values.

Anyone know a fix for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_match('~^/[a-z]{2}(?:/|$)~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('~^/[a-z]{2}(?:/)?~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
```

Comment: this will match 2 chars after every slash.

Comment: Don't know if it matters, but that will also match `http://www.mydomain.com/enfoo`.